# What does Vlastov’s 1954 paper really mean

Tags: aristotle, plato, parmenides

I’m Attempting to find out the counter arguments to the Third man argument.
And while researching came across Vlastov’s 1954 Paper ‘The third man argument in Parmenides’ (*The Philosophical Review* 63, pp. 319-349) and being 16 struggle to understand the highly academic language, which I’m not used to.
If anyone understands and could explain that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe useful [Plato: The Third Man Argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-parmenides/#ThiManArg132)

Comment: You can see also [The Cambridge Companion to Plato](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Cambridge_Companion_to_Plato/QmmBpP41slwC): **Ch.12** is dedicated to the "Third Man argument".

Comment: Formally speaking, third man argument is simply Russell-Zermelo paradox. Does set that contains all large objects contains it self ? Does set containing all men contains itself ? As such, there is no proof pro or contra, it all depends how do you define sets (forms) .